# Why does chrome webrtc allocate two relay ports when transport is tcp and only one for udp?

Tags: webrtc, turn

Access Trickle ICE test site:

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

When using url=`turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=udp`, it behaves normally and only one realy candidate is allocated.

When using url=`turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp`, it behaves strangely and there are two candidate allocated for realy.

Why?

[image: one relay candidate for udp]

[image: two relay candidates for tcp]